# Solving libjscexecutor.so error appearing in Crashlytics

Tags: android, react-native, crashlytics, libs

I am constantly seeing the following error in the application on the Crashlytics. Since this error did not occur on my own device, I cannot see if my fixes will work. What is the exact solution to this problem and what do I need to do so that my own devices can see this issue?

[image]

Comment: Don't you see device model or brand name where this issue happen then you can reproduce with that device or emulate it

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?